# Asus k200ma dso1t Ubuntu dual boot compatibility

Tags: dual-boot, asus, compatibility

I just ordered an Asus k200ma dso1t laptop and I want to dual boot it with windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. Can I do that? Does it work on all Asus computers?

Answer (score 1):

99% the answer would be "yes" - but not 100% sure.
It's impossible to tell about ALL Asus computers, but really I've never seen a modern laptop being unable to run Ubuntu and Windows in dual boot. (Maybe I'm just lucky ;))

I recommend you to try Xubuntu or Lubuntu, they should run faster than Ubuntu.

Comment: What about Elementary OS?

Comment: Why use xubuntu lubuntu? Is Ubuntu to slow?

Comment: You can try them by booting from LiveUSB and make your own opinion ;) Usually Xubuntu/Lubuntu are faster.

Comment: I would like to have a Mac OS X macbuntu theme. Can you do that on xubuntu?